# I was trying to delete a folder which its location was not found

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

So I was trying to delete a folder which its location could not be found. I googled up a forum and found a fix:

```
type rd /s "\\?\..."
```

into cmd so i did and more folder route was on the desktop. Here's my first mess up

```
rd /s "\\?\C:\users\name\desktop" 
enter
rd /s "\\?\C:\users\name\desktop\new folder (3)
enter
```

This command takes some time because nothing happened at first. I restart my computer and saw an empty desktop except for a few things. There go my folders of school work and pictures, all my games shortcuts and various amounts of other things. It's ok I'll just do a system restore

Queue second mess up. Apparently with in the last four years i turned the option of for system restore in the system protection. So my last backup is from 2015.

I have no idea what to do. I hope there is some kind of magic undo for,

```
rd /s "\\?\C:\users\name\desktop"
```

but i seriously doubt there is. Please help.

I am using windows 7.

I tried data recovery tool Recuva. Which it recovered the files I wanted, but all the files were bad and or corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Contents deleted this way are not placed in the Recycle Bin.
Another problem is that while using Windows on this disk, you may be overwriting
the contents you are trying to recover.

If Recuva cannot return them, try other products from the article
[Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm).

Use products that have a boot CD or USB. Do not boot your computer on this disk,
so prepare this boot media on another computer.

I'm sorry to say that the chances of saving the files are not good.